# How to modify numpy arrays using multiple masks

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have an array `a`:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
```

I can make a mask:

```
mask1 = a > 2
```

and then view the masked array:

```
[In]: a[mask1]

[Out]: array([3, 4, 5])
```

or modify it:

```
a[mask1] = [8, 9, 10]

[In]: a
[Out]: array([ 1,  2,  8,  9, 10])
```

Now I want to mask the masked array again, based on some other criteria, e.g.:

```
mask2 = a[mask1] > 8
```

and I can view it:

```
[In]: a[mask1][mask2]
[Out]: array([ 9, 10])
```

Now **here is the problem**; when I try to modify the doubly-masked array, it doesn't work anymore:

```
a[mask1][mask2] = [20, 30]

[In]: a
[Out]: array([ 1,  2,  8,  9, 10])
```

I know it has to do with numpy returning views of arrays and so, but why does it work with one mask, but not with multiple masks, and how can I make it work with multiple masks?

Answer (score 0):

Update array with chained index should generally be avoided.

You can convert the masks into range index and update, something like this:

```
idx = np.arange(len(a))[mask1][mask2]
a[idx] = [20, 30]
```

Output:

```
array([ 1,  2,  8, 20, 30])
```

Comment: But this only works for 1-dimensional arrays. What if the array is multi-dimensional?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found 'a' solution, but don't know if it's the best solution:

I create a `current_mask` array with the shape of my array, and initialize it to all `True`:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
current_mask = np.ones(a.shape, dtype=np.bool_)
```

Then, whenever I create a new mask, I update my `current_mask` with it:

```
mask1 = a > 2
current_mask[current_mask] &= mask1
```

Like before, I can view and modify the elements using `current_mask`:

```
[In]: a[current_mask]
[Out]: array([3, 4, 5])

[In]: a[current_mask] = [8,9,10]
[In]: a
[Out]: array([ 1,  2,  8,  9, 10])
```

Now, I can create a new mask using the current mask, and update the current mask with it:

```
mask2 = a[current_mask] > 8
current_mask[current_mask] &= mask2
```

Now, I can both view AND modify the elements:

```
[In]: a[current_mask]
[Out]: array([ 9, 10])

[In]: a[current_mask] = [20, 30]
[In]: a
[Out]: array([ 1,  2,  8, 20, 30])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using `numpy.logical_and` will work for your needs

```
a = np.arange(10).reshape(5, 2)
mask_sup_2 = a > 3
mask_inf_8 = a < 8

mask_2_and_8 = np.logical_and(mask_sup_2, mask_inf_8)

a[mask_2_and_8] = 10
```

results in

```
[[ 0  1]
 [ 2  3]
 [10 10]
 [10 10]
 [ 8  9]]
```